# Dealing with abbreviation and misspelled words in DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe contains misspelled words and abbreviations like this.

```py
input:
df = pd.DataFrame(['swtch', 'cola', 'FBI', 
      'smsng', 'BCA', 'MIB'], columns=['misspelled'])

output:
       misspelled
0   swtch
1   cola
2   FBI
3   smsng
4   BCA
5   MIB
```

I need to correcting the misspelled words and the Abvreviations

I have tried with creating the dictionary such as:

```py
input: 
dicts = pd.DataFrame(['coca cola', 'Federal Bureau of Investigation', 
                    'samsung', 'Bank Central Asia', 'switch', 'Men In Black'], columns=['words'])

output:
        words
0   coca cola
1   Federal Bureau of Investigation
2   samsung
3   Bank Central Asia
4   switch
5   Men In Black
```

and applying this code

```py
x = [next(iter(x), np.nan) for x in map(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, dicts.words), df.misspelled)]
df['fix'] = x

print (df)
```

The output is I have succeded correcting misspelled but not the abbreviation

```
misspelled        fix
0      swtch     switch
1       cola  coca cola
2        FBI        NaN
3      smsng    samsung
4        BCA        NaN
5        MIB        NaN
```

Please help.

Comment: How many abbreviations do you have in your data?

Comment: @Erfan what if we say it is 10 million rows and 20% of them is abbvreviations so it is around 200k data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about following a 2-prong approach where first correct the misspellings and then expand the abbreviations:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['swtch', 'cola', 'FBI', 'smsng', 'BCA', 'MIB'], columns=['misspelled'])
abbreviations = {
    'FBI': 'Federal Bureau of Investigation',
    'BCA': 'Bank Central Asia',
    'MIB': 'Men In Black',
    'cola': 'Coca Cola'
}

spell = SpellChecker()
df['fixed'] = df['misspelled'].apply(spell.correction).replace(abbreviations)
```

Result:

```
  misspelled                            fixed
0      swtch                           switch
1       cola                        Coca Cola
2        FBI  Federal Bureau of Investigation
3      smsng                            among
4        BCA                Bank Central Asia
5        MIB                     Men In Black
```

I use [`pyspellchecker`](https://pypi.org/project/pyspellchecker/) but you can go with any spelling-checking library. It corrected `smsng` to `among` but that is a caveat of automatic spelling correction. Different libraries may give out different results